# Trying to create a Android widget button for my application that opens a Java activity, sending URI data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

So, there are a lot of questions on this but none of the answers have worked and my problem is unique. I am trying to set URI data so I can send that in an intent to a java class from a widget button I have created. I know the widget button is set up correctly because it sends the toast message when clicked.

**The problem is:** no intent, or variation of intents, I send, after clicking the button, works. It always crashes and the logcat gives a mostly non-descriptive reason why, pointing to the `startActivity(i)`. Any help would be much appreciated. Complete code for the widget is below:

```
package com.matthewbenchimol.cydogbrowser;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;
import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class Dashboard extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String MyOnClick = "myOnClickTag";

    void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int appWidgetId) {
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.dashboard);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Dashboard.class);
        intent.setAction(MyOnClick);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton, pendingIntent);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        String url = "https://test.com";
        if (intent.getAction().equals(MyOnClick)) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Under-development", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Sandbox.class);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of what you’re trying to do? Not only the imports…

Comment: Instead of `setData` you can use `putExtra` method. [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: That lists the entire widget Java class, including the imports. You have to scroll down. The section in question is in the onReceive.

Comment: Why you are launching a broadcast? Do you really need to have a one, or you can just launch the activity?

Comment: @Zain, that's how the Android Widget architecture works. If you have a better method, please post and I'll take a look. I tried `putExtra` instead of `setData` @YaMiN and it didn't work. Note: I realize the code has `intent.setData` instead of `i.setData`. I was testing a multitude of different methods. It doesn't work when it's change to the correct syntax of `i.setData`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the purpose of the broadcast you launch whenever the widget button is clicked; but I believe that the `Uri` data should be attached to intent that is associated with the `PendingIntent` which will be registered in the system in `onUpdate()` callback.

So, if you just really want to send `Uri` data to the activity without no specific need to the broadcast receiver; you can just attach it to the intent of the `PendingIntent` associated to the button.

```
public class Dashboard extends AppWidgetProvider {

    void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int appWidgetId) {
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.dashboard);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Sandbox.class);
        String url = "https://test.com";
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton, pendingIntent);
    
        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    //.... 

}
```

This will send the Uri to the activity:

```
public class Sandbox extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(....);  

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null) {
            Uri data = intent.getData(); // Should contain `https://test.com`
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onCreate: data: " + data); 
        } else {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onCreate: data: Null");
        }
    }
}
```